# How to add two Actions to a button In react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a problem in combine 2 action in the same button

```
<Button
disabled={!isFormValid}`
onClicked={this.submitHandler}
/>
```

I want to add this function with the 
previous one

```
() => this.popUpHandler('update');
```

[This my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2OP4.png)

The first action to submit form and next to close popup after that.
Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: please add your code as a snippet in the post

Comment: if you can post your code in https://codesandbox.io/ it will be easy to track your bug.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Anonymous_functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions).

```
<Button
    disabled={!isFormValid}
    onClicked={ () => {
        this.popupHandler("Update");
        console.log('Button clicked');
    }}
/>
```

Or create a separate handler;

```
Class Something extends React.Component {
  onButtonClick() {
      // Do anything
      this.popupHandler("Update");
      console.log('Button clicked');
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Button
            disabled={!isFormValid}
            onClicked={this.onButtonClick()}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
    submitHandler(){
    //after some condition  you can call here another function

    this.popUpHandler('update')

    }
    popUpHandler(var){
    //your logic
    }
<Button
    disabled={!isFormValid}
    onClicked={this.submitHandler}
/>
```

Comment: If you are trying to call consecutive function you can do this.

Comment: ` submitHandler = event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.Enroll(this.state);
  }; ` <= this submitHandler , how to include inside it  this fanction ? () =>  this.popUpHander('update')

Comment: You can simply  `submitHandler = event => { event.preventDefault(); this.props.Enroll(this.state); this.popUpHandler('update') }; `. Is your submitHandler being trigger when you submit form?